# First eigenvalue for strictly convex domains

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, eigenvalues, laplacian

Let $M^n$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with boundary, suppose 1). $Ric(M)\ge (n-1)$ and 2). the principle curvatures of the boundary is bounded from below by $h\ge 0$. Is there any results on the bound of first eigenvalue of the Laplacian with Dirichlet boundary condition?

If $h=0$, then it is the classical Obata's theorem, which says $\lambda_1\ge n$.

How about the other two lower Ricci curvature bounds $-(n-1)$ and $0$?

Comment: From my paper on harmonic functions in Alexandrov space one gets $\lambda_1\ge n$ in case $sec\ge 1$. But the same argument works in your case since there is some lower bound on sectional curvature.